# Adding custom items in "My Favorites" of Team Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, tfs, team-explorer

There is in Team Explorer the area 'My Favorites", where links to WI queries, Docs, Reports & Builds of any Team Project of the Collection can be added.
I recently added a set of central/highly viewable documents in the 'Shared Documents' section of the Collection (http://tfs/sites/"CollectionName"/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx), which obviously are not per se available in Team Explorer.
I would like to add them as links in the 'My Favorites' section, does anybody know a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to add "favorites" for others.  The next version of TFS does have this functionality which is called "Team Favorities", but it's not available in 2010.

Why isn't SharePoint working for you?  Your SharePoint folders should show up in Team Explorer just fine.  See the image here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997580.aspx

Comment: Hello Aaron & thanks for your answer, although it does break bad news..Documents residing in Sharepoint-sites that are under any of my Team Project do allow linking. My problem was/is with artifacts residing under `Shared Documents` of the Team Collection, which aren't present in the Team Explorer and apparently can't also be imported in the "My Favorites" section.